# How to check if a java process in unix is killed?

Tags: process, java, kill

I have a java application on Unix. This application unexpectedly stops. I am looking for what is the problem.

How can I tell in a java process started on Unix, if this process is being killed? (with `kill -9 pid`) I can't modify the code, I can't do a catch. I can modify the boot in java with `-verbose`. Something is killing that process....

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java \
-verbose \
-classpath '../../lib/*:.:./config' com.xxx.xxx.core.xxxxApp instance:$INSTANCE
```

But it does not appear in the logs. Any other method?

Comment: Does it even start? Can you wrap it in a `bash` script? The command you give is not a valid command. Your `classpath` depends on what directory (`$PWD`) you're in, "`com.xxx.xxx.core.xxxxApp` followed by the rest does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As waltinator suggested in the comment to you question, you can run your process with a shell script.  That script can block waiting for your process to terminate, then inspect the exit status to get some idea of the failure mode.

Generally if a process is terminated by a signal, the exist status is 128 plus the signal number.  For example, if someone did a `kill -9` on the process, then the exit status would be 137 (128 + 9 = 137).

For example, here's a script that runs your command and prints a message if it terminated in response to a signal:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java \
    -verbose \
    -classpath '../../lib/*:.:./config' com.xxx.xxx.core.xxxxApp instance:$INSTANCE

rc=$? # The $? variable has the exit status of the previous command


if [[ ${rc} -gt 128 ]]; then
    printf "Process terminated with signal %d\n" $((rc - 128))
fi
```

Now, if I use `kill -9` to terminate the `java` process, then I get:

```
Process terminated with signal 9
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems kernel is killing the process due to some problems, for example if a process is consuming too much memory then the kernel **Out of Memory** (OOM) killer will automatically kill the offending process. You can make sure by checking logs for any kernel related error logs:

```
egrep -i 'killed process' /var/log/messages
```

or

```
egrep -i -r 'killed process' /var/log
```

I suggest to check system logs and see the logs related to the process of java program you are executing.

```
dmesg | grep -i kill
```

This one for example displays logs related to kill to check full logs you can use:

```
dmesg | less
```

system logs give you detailed information why the process is killed is it memory issue or any other.

If someone is killing this process there needs to be super user you can check `/var/log/auth.log` for `kill` command